# 2 consecutive calls with xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am making a sort of chat with JS and PHP.

every 3 seconds the app make a GET xmlhttp request to get messages, and every 3 seconds makes POST to set the lastSeen infos.

I cant understand why the POST call works and the GET call dont.

I already checked other posts on this argument and tried but the problem remains.

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        window.setInterval(stampa, 3000);

        $('#invia').click(function () {

            var inp = $('#input').val();

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://ritapp.altervista.org/chatData.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var sendData = "type=" + "post" + "&nome1=" + "CAVI" + "&pic1=" + "imm1" + "&nome2=" + "CLALTAR" + "&pic2=" + "imm2" + "&text=" + inp;

            xmlhttp.send(sendData);

        });

    });


    function stampa() {
        var chatData;
        downloadUrl("http://ritapp.altervista.org/chatData.php?type=get&nome1=" + "CAVI",
            function (data) {

                var xml = data.responseXML;

                chatData = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("get");


                for (var i = 0; i < chatData.length; i++) {

                    var nome1 = chatData[i].getAttribute("nome1"); //0

                    var pic1 = chatData[i].getAttribute("pic1");
                    var nome2 = chatData[i].getAttribute("nom2"); //1
                    var pic2 = chatData[i].getAttribute("pic2"); //2
                    var text = chatData[i].getAttribute("text"); //3
                    var data = chatData[i].getAttribute("data"); //4 


                    var tutto = nome1 + ": " + text + "<br/>";
                    $('#content').append(tutto);
                    alert("appendo");
                }



                if (chatData.length > 0) {

                    $('#content').trigger();


                }

            });

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {

                aggiornaLastSeen("http://ritapp.altervista.org/chatData.php", function () {});

            }
        };

    }

    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);

    }


    function aggiornaLastSeen(url, callback) {

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        var sendUser = "type=" + "chatUser" + "&nome1=" + "CAVI" + "&pic1=" + "imm1";

        request.open('POST', url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(sendUser);

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's developer tools? What sort of error is the 'get' request generating?

Comment: The problem is that you're sharing a single variable, `request`, for both calls. Possible problem: the GET call runs, but before it can complete, `requests` gets overwritten by the POST request, so when the GET resolves, `callback(request, request.status)` refers to the POST request, before it has completed. Why don't you put two separate `request` declarations inside your `downloadURL` and `aggiornaLastSeen` functions?

Comment: i tried to make 2 different xml http requesto but doesnt work.
@Nick - no errors is generated the request goes but nothing happens

Comment: @apsillers - if i make 2 different calls the POST request goes before the GET request even if the function to call is at the end